# Official name of the new Jobs site?

Tags: support, jobs, legal, trademark

I was taking a look at the [trademark guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) where it says what the proper use of the Stack Exchange name involves. However, it's not addressing the new jobs site.

I believe on `careers.stackoverflow.com` the official name was *Stack Overflow Careers* or *Careers 2.0*. The bottom bar still says "Stack Overflow Careers" and redirects to `careers.stackoverflow.com`:

[image]

That page states it has moved to **"Stack Overflow Jobs"**

[image]

but the [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow?) calls it **Jobs on Stack Overflow**

[image]

Better yet, the source on the jobs page has a different title

```
<title> Jobs  - Stack Overflow</title>
```

So, I'm just wondering - ***what's the official or preferred name?***

Comment: Eh, could view this as a question on the trademark guidance too, which is network-wide. Probably best to err on the side of caution while this stuff is getting hashed out.